# SharePoint designer create task - normal user can't send email - Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I've a problem with a SharePoint designer workflow. The workflow creates a new task and for this an email will be sent to the task owner. Everything works fine during my tests with Administrator privileges.

Tests with users which have only Edit privileges failed with an error message (HTTP Forbidden). The Task is created but sending the mail failed and the workflow stops. The message tell me that they don't have the mandatory access rights.

[image: error message]

Pressing redo as adminstrator sends the mail and restart the workflow.

I already tried to start the site feature 'Workflow can use app permission' and also to grant the site app permissions in appinv.aspx, unfortunately without success.

Has anybody an idea why sending mails failed for user with edit rights?

BR
Andreas

Comment: If "Workflow can use app permission' feature activated. You can add "app step" in workflow designer in that app step add the send email action to send emails. This "app step" works like run with admin privilages

Comment: Can you give vote and check answer for my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "Workflow can use app permission' feature activated. You can add "app step" in workflow designer in that app step add the send email action to send emails. This "app step" works like run with admin privilages